# is it possible to function(column1) AS column1? or column1 = function(column1)?

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to

```
function(column1) AS column1
```

or

```
column1 = function(column1)
```

?

Comment: If you put a `select` in front, then you can do either.  But they do different things, so you should choose the one that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, you can use functions as a result:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,last_name) AS full_name FROM my_table
```